# What should I look for in a cookie jar?

Tags: equipment, cookies

I would like to upgrade from the novelty plastic bin I currently use for cookies. What cookie jar features would prevent the cookies from getting stale for the longest amount of time? What shape of jar will allow for storing the most cookies? Is light sensitivity a factor?

Comment: How long do you keep your cookies in the jar?

Comment: I'd like to extend the life of the cookies to a little over a week. Currently they start getting stale around day 4.

Comment: Cookies! (There are hats; I'm allowed to have fun now, right?)

Comment: Do you have a most common *type* of cookie you keep?

Comment: Let's say it's snickerdoodles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found a [cookie jar buying guide](http://www.walmart.com/c/bg/cookie-jar-buying-guide) on Walmart.com that has some interesting tidbits. For functionality alone, looks like a glass jar should do the job well. Something like this would have an advantageous shape to make cookies easier to reach, and the jar less prone to falling.

[image: best-cookie0jar]

One feature you may want to look for specifically would be an hermetic sealing lid, which would help keep moisture in the jar and slow down the drying. Same kind of jar that is often used to store flour, sugar, coffee, beans, etc.

[image: hermetic-jar]

> Is light sensitivity a factor?

I don't think it would be, in most cases, unless you kept your cookies in an area that is heavily lit by the sun.

Comment: "I don't think it would be, in most cases, unless you kept your cookies in an area that is heavily lit by the sun." Doesn't glass provide some protection from heat caused by sunlight anyway, due to blocking ultraviolet?

Comment: It does to an extent, yes. I was more concerned about the heat from the sun, which could affect the texture. I will add clarification!

Comment: actually, it turns out ultraviolet is a much smaller proportion of the energy from sunlight than I thought, so it's irrelevant. Sorry.

Comment: Well, more info is better than less, I guess. I still think sunlight would be the very least significant factor, either way :)

Comment: If it's a dry (or moist due to oil, not water) cookie, I wouldn't think that glass would be a problem.  Typically moist things in glass containers are a problem as the water evaporates, then condenses on the inside of the jar.

Comment: The only thing I would add to this answer is that it's important to consider the size of the opening to the jar - so that you can insert and retrieve large cookies without breaking them.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do for anything which goes bad (rancid) due to oxygenation is to spritz into the jar a bit of canned air sold for keyboard cleaning. These cans contain a refrigerant gas which is heavier than air, so even a little bit in a bottle or can of oil keeps the oxygen away from the oil.

It will work with cookies and other things as well since it stays on top of oils, you only need to hit them once. I don't know about cookies...they never last long enough to go stale!

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. The air in most such "canned air" aerosols is mixed with a [bitterant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitterant) to keep people from huffing the gas, and there's no way you want that bitterant on your food.